# How to install DB Browser for SQLite via PPA?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

On the [website](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) they have mentioned to user ppa

For Ubuntu and derivaties, @deepsidhu1313 provides a PPA with our latest release here:

```
   https://launchpad.net/~linuxgndu/+archive/ubuntu/sqlitebrowser
```

I added these two lines

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu trusty main
```

to software & update > other software > add > paster the two lines one by one and added both separately

I ran `sudo apt-get update` but I get error saying public key didn't match

The [ppa at launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~linuxgndu/+archive/ubuntu/sqlitebrowser?field.series_filter=trusty) has mentioned signing key & fingerprint but I am not sure where to add which one of them to pass the error.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so adding the below line fixed the issue

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7F2583EA
```

then `sudo apt-get update`

install software `sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser`

Reference: Ubuntu [forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1263676)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, i think they haven't updated their main page. I will tell them.

[Link to github repo and instructions.](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser#ubuntu-and-derivatives)

Here you go
add repo using following command

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser
```

Then install the package

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
```

if you want to use daily builds

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing
```

followed by same commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
```

Enjoy !!